# Properties file sleep

Tags: java

I have class which will load the property keys.  During execution it sleeps for 20 seconds, and while it is sleeping, I add a new key to the property file and save it. When the program wakes up, it again reads the property file, but its output does not show the property added during its sleep.  How can I make the program recognize the property file change?

Here is my current code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "com/vijayspring/common/CityIns.properties");

        try {
            props.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(props.stringPropertyNames());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Properties props1 = new Properties();
        InputStream is1 = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                "com/vijayspring/common/CityIns.properties");

        try {
            props1.load(is1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(props1.stringPropertyNames());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you save the properties file? And are you aware that you load the properties from a immutable location?

Comment: iam saving in src folder of the project and it is loading the keys and printing in console

Comment: Please add that part of code, it is vital for your question.

Comment: @M.leRutte, I think he's saying that he *manually* modifies the properties file.

Answer (score 1):

As you are referring to a `src` folder, I assume you are using an IDE. If I knew which IDE it is exactly, I could be more accurate with my answer.

Nevertheless, the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` method is reading the property file from the `bin` *(the actual name might vary per IDE)* folder, which is usually built by the IDE once when it launches the java program. Any files that are no java source files, hence do not end with `.java` are simply copied from `src` to `bin`.

So after 20 seconds your program will read the unedited properties file in the `bin` folder.

Comment: My thought the same. In case of Intellij it would be target directory. A typical case when reading with a relative path. Typically IDE is the one which hot swaps the file into the output dir whenever a new change happens.

Comment: thanks and you are right I have edited the properties in the bin and now its working